# How to get/return viewtype in use from adapter?

Tags: android, view, return, adapter

is there a way I can get/return a `View` in my case a `RecyclerView` from the `Adapter` using it so as to reuse it in another `Activity`. And if possible how can I then re use it in the `Activity`?Without re-referencing it a new in the `Activity`

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: What is your question? It's very unclear to me.

Comment: well picture this I have an adapter in which a layout is inflated.In that layout I have a recyclerview.So my question is can I at a point return that recyclerView and use it in another activity without having to reinflate it.

Comment: In that case, I think the answer is **no**. As @SerjArdovic said, you can reuse your adapter which will repopulate your `RecyclerView` in other activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question right, you are asking whether an `Adapter` for RecyclerView you have in an `Activity` can be used for another `RecyclerView` in another `Activity`. In that case, **the answer is - YES, it can be used** in as many places you wish..

Don't forget, `Adapter` is nothing but a **design pattern** in programming:

> Adapter pattern works as a bridge between two incompatible interfaces.
>   This type of design pattern comes under structural pattern as this
>   pattern combines the capability of two independent interfaces.

As long as you have your `Adapter` class accessible (not a private inner class) by your other `Activity`, you can reuse it with different `RecyclerView` and different data.

Comment: not quite.This is what i meant...well picture this I have an adapter in which a layout is inflated.In that layout I have a recyclerview.So my question is can I at a point return that recyclerView and use it in another activity without having to reinflate it.

Comment: @Thekamble - First of all, please make your questions more clear and understandable. Secondly, regarding your clarification, again the answer is **NO** - you inflate XML, which is attached to your Activity Context, after you pass onto next Activity, you'll have to inflate again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.And i'll look into bettering my questions's structure next time.Again thanks for the clarification.